# Importing CSV in Talend double quote delimited column is ignored

Tags: csv, talend, double-quotes

I have a CSV file with a double quote delimited timestamp and an email field, e.g.

```
Timestamp,Email
"2017-01-01 00:00:01",abc@email.com
"2017-01-01 00:02:31",sampleaddress@email2.com
```

I have defined a metadata source for the CSV file and it was correctly able to identify and type the two columns. When I execute the package however, it treats the timestamp column as though it doesn't exist (usually I get an error 'Unparseable date: "abc@email.com"')

I have tried altering the tFileInputDelimited with a number of settings, including the escape and text enclosure options and importing the timestamp as both a date and string (If I import it as a string, the timestamp field has the email address and the email address is blank), but I am unable to get the import to recognise the existence of the double quote delimited timestamp column.

I'm assuming that I have done something that is causing it to escape the whole timestamp value, but I can't think of what that might be.

Comment: The doublequotes are from a mailchimp extract. I don't have any control over the input format.

Comment: I resolved the problem by resetting the component to use metadata defined in the repository, but these other solutions are valid too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to keep the double quote around the timestamp in your input file, try this date model

```
"\"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss\""
```

This way, you specify that you need double quotes (\") in the input string.

Comment: The double quotes are from a mailchimp extract. I don't have any control over the format of the input files, barring modifying them from within Talend.

Comment: This is a clever idea though - and if I had not already solved it I would have gone with this solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you can alter the input data, you should either enable quotes for all fields or for none.

If this is no option, you could also read the file with *tFileInputFullRow*, remove the quotes with a String replace maybe and process the data afterwards with *tDenormalize* into column data.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using metadata, then:

1. Ensure that the component is referring to the repository (Component -> Property Type = Repository)
2. Modify the metadata to change the text enclosure character to "\""